# why i want to show "hello world"with react+ES6+npm,but it cat't show anything

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

```
//html code
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <script type="text/babel"></script>
       <div id="content"></div>   //show the content of component here
    </body>
  </html>

//js code
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import React from 'react';

class Calculate extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <p>Hello, world!</p>;
    }
}

render(<Calculate />, document.getElementById('content'));
```

File directory structure:
[image: File directory structure]

package.json:
[image: package.json]

I want to show "hello world"in the html page without webpack to babel nor online files,because i use npm tool download react,react-dom and babel to node_modules,then i use "import React from 'react';"to import what i need,but see nothing in the page,i can't know why

Comment: In your script tag - why didn't you include the script source?

Comment: I have tried,but it is still show nothing,and i don't think it is needed,in js file,if it  can render the content in the specified tag

Comment: You need to load the javascript from `index.html` somehow.

Comment: I mean one way can achieve my thought,that's use webpack to babel,but now i don't want to use it.I want to use the simplest way to achieve

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a bundle file from all your js files using webpack,provide a path to that bundle file in your script tag and place the script tag below the div with id=content

Answer (score -2):

Hey bruh but what is that `<div>` tag for?
It doesn't describe anything.
First make some content in your `<div>`
for example:

```
<head>
<style>
.container {
     width: 20px;
     height: 20px;
     background-color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
```

This is just a example,but for js use `<script>` tag.

```
<script>
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import React from 'react';

class Calculate extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <p>Hello, world!</p>;
    }
}

render(<Calculate />, document.getElementById('content'));
</script>
```

Whoops I made a mistake, `REALLY` gave there this, it was written on my starter notes And i have saw it and though it is ok.Sorry. ;-)

Comment: *`<div>` is for CSS*? what do you mean by that? `div` is a container.

Comment: I tried with your way,but it does't work,the div is a container  where i want to render my content of component

Comment: *Hey bruh but what is that `<div>` tag for?* - I don't know, maybe **a container to render the component to**...